# Usage of non anaconda module in python script written using jupiter editor

Tags: anaconda, jupyter-notebook

I just started exploring python scripting. I am using anaconda/jupyter editor.

I have a python executable let's say "new-crawler", I have installed it using "pip install new-crawler". It is installed in the correct environment, python etc.
I am able to import the module in jupyter.

However, I am running into an issue "SyntaxError: invalid syntax".

Script:

```
%aimport news-crawler as nc 
nc reports USA -o out.csv -s 20160101 -e 20161231 -keyword election.
```

Error points right after "reports".
I assume this is because of passing multiple arguments.
I really appreciate any help with proper python syntax here.
Thanks in advance.

Same line works fine from command line.

Comment: have you tried with `--` before keyword?

Comment: that is not the problem, for whatever reason 2nd argument is resulting in syntax error. Same line works fine from command line.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the answer.
Command:

```
news-crawler reports USA -o out.csv -s 20160101 -e 20161231 -keyword election
```

is a command to run the executable in shell, not IPython commands.
I just had to prefix the command with ! to run in IPython.